# grails service with quartz

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I wrote an app in Grails but I have some problems with quartz.
I wanna fetch User from DB and after that fetch his servers as well.
If there will be any server I wanna check PING command on each one, but I get a message like this:

> "
>       [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job:
>   GRAILS_JOBS.
>       Message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
>   web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
>   receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
>   and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
>   of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.
>         Line | Method
>       ->>  96 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
>       - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
>       |   216 | run     in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
>       ^   549 | run . . in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
>       Caused by IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to
>   request attributes outside of an actual web
>   request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving
>   thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still
>   receive this message, your code is probably running outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.
>       ->> 131 | currentRequestAttributes in org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder"

This is my code:

```
 def execute() {
     pingService.checkPing()
 }



 def checkPing = {
     User user = User.findByLogin(session.user.login) //get user
     def hostsToPing = importFromDB()
     if (!hostsToPing.isEmpty()) {
         hostsToPing.each {host ->
             doPing(host)
         }
     } else {
         //something else
     }
 }

 def importFromDB = {
     User user = User.findByLogin(session.user.login)
     def hostsList = Host.findAllByUser(user)
     hostsList
 }

 def doPing(Host host) {
     println "InetAdress: " + InetAddress.getByName(host.hostAdress)
     println "InetAdress is Rea: " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().isReachable(1000)
 }
```

There isn't this problem when is something like this:

```
def doPing(Host host) {
    println "InetAdress: " + InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com")
    println "InetAdress is Reachable : " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().isReachable(1000)
}
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're referring to `session.user.login`. There is no `session` in a `Job`, period. 
Imagine the job is started when no user is logged in - WHAT user are you referring then?

So either check every user in `User.list()` or make a singleton bean with a users queue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with User.list().